# Defining function templates

Tags: c++, templates

I'm wondering what expression  `cT::value_type` in example below tells to compiler? I can write watever I wont insted of word `value_type` - it builds anyway. Looks like code is trying to tell compiler '`cT` type should have some property (o maybe vector member, but it is not visible in template definition) that type will be used for second function parameter'. How far is my understanding from reality?

How compiler knows that both params should be taken as string:

```
joinContainer(s1, ':');
```

In compiler place I would expect something like

```
joinContainer<string,string>(s1, ':');
```

or event maybe

```
<string>joinContainer<string,string>(s1, ':');
```

Whole code:

```
// join.cpp by Bill Weinman <http://bw.org/>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename cT, typename retT = cT, typename sepT = decltype(cT::value_type)>
retT joinContainer(const cT & o, const sepT & sep) {
    retT out;

    auto it = o.begin();
    while(it != o.end())
    {
        out += *it;
        if(++it != o.end()) out += sep;
    }
    return out;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    string s1("This is a string");
    string s2("This is also a string");
    string s3("Yet another string");

    // join the characters of a string


    cout << joinContainer<string, string>(s1, ':') << endl;

    // join strings from a vector, returning a string
    vector<string> vs({s1, s2, s3});
    cout << joinContainer<vector<string>, string>(vs, ", ");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by  'broken compiler'

Answer (score 0):

The compiler gets sepT template parameter from the 2. function parameter, so it probably never uses the default parameter (`cT::value_type`). So it probably never instantiates a template that uses the default value of the third template parameter.

As to your second question why you can write `joinContainer(s1, ':');` and it works. The compiler has all the information it needs. The 1. and 3. template parameters are deduced from the function arguments. The 2. template parameter is not specified, but there is a default one for it in the definition so the compiler uses that.

```
joinContainer(s1, ':'); 
cT - type std::string (deduced from s1)
retT - type std::string (default value used, which is the same as cT)
sepT - type const char (deduced from ':')

joinContainer<string,string>(s1, ':'); 
cT - type std::string (because you specified in the template parameters)
retT - type std::string (because you specified in the template parameters)
sepT - type const char (deduced from ':')
note: if s1 would not be of type std::string there would be a compiler error

<string>joinContainer<string,string>(s1, ':'); 
Will not compile.
```

Answer (score 0):

This example seems a bit illogical. Basically it's like this:

```
template<typename T = Foo>
void f(const T & x)
{
    // print x, whatever...
}
```

(the “`typename T = Foo`” is like the “`typename sepT = decltype(cT::value_type)`”, and the “`const T & x`” like the “`const sepT & sep`”).

Now, how many ways are there to call this function? Only one:

```
    f(obj); // whatever type obj is
```

That is, you must always pass an argument, and `T` will always be deduced, so `Foo` *will never be used*.

(Ok, you can also force the template argument, like `f<Bar>(obj);`, but `Foo` still won't be used, and you should not do that anyway.)

A more logical example would be:

```
template<typename T = Foo>
void g(const T & x = T())
{
    // print x, whatever...
}
```

Now, thanks to both the default value (type) for the template parameter and the default value for the function parameter, you can call it with or without argument:

```
    g(obj);
    g();    // equivalent to g(Foo());
```

In the argument-less call, the default `Foo` for `T` is used.

---

*Moreover*, “`decltype(cT::value_type)`” is **invalid**: `decltype` takes an expression, not a type. Maybe the author meant `typename sepT = typename cT::value_type` (the additional “`typename`” is needed).